# MongoDB: min(), max() doesn't support embedded document

Tags: mongodb, max, min

I have applied index on embedded document field which is of type date. Due to unpredictable behavior of MongoDB query with $lt & $gt operators I am trying to use min() max() functions of Cursor which force both lower & upper bounds on the index. But when I used it, it gave me error:

```
planner returned error: unable to find relevant index for max/min query"
```

Query looks like:

```
db.user.find().min({'record.date':ISODate("2014-12-01")}).max({'record.date':ISODate("2014-12-01")}).explain()
```

I have indexed the field 'record.date'. I even tried to force it with hint() but of no use. It showed me this error:

```
planner returned error: hint provided does not work with min query"
```

Somewhere on the Internet I saw on one of the forums that we can query with embedded fields in min(), max() functions. Field 'record' is an array of sub-documents. I have another field of type date in main document for which min(), max() worked fine (this field is indexed too). Can anyone guess why is this happening?

sample document:
user:

```
{name:'ad',dob: ISODate('yyyy-mm-dd'),createdAt: ISODate(),...,record:[
```

{date:ISODate:(),...
},...]}

Index was created as:

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'record.date':1})
```

Thanks.

Comment: "unpredictable behavior of MongoDB query with $lt & $gt operators"?  That's probably the question you should be asking.  Anyway, using these modifiers on an embedded field worked fine when I tried it, so it should work.

Comment: I have found the reason for "unpredictable". It's because of the MongoDB working that it takes one bound in consideration at a time. It works sometime with both the bounds but then that's what is unpredictable. I guess especially for large data set.

Comment: @harshad That's why you use `$elemMatch` when using `$lt` and `$gt` together on the same field of array elements.  It constrains the match to be on the same element.

Comment: @JohnnyHK but my question is not about that. Why min(), max() functions aren't working with record.date index?