# MongoDB: degraded query performance

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

I have a user's collection in MongoDB with over 2.5 million of records which constitute to 30 GB. I have about 4 to 6 GB of indexes. It's in sharded environment with two shards, each consisting of replica set. Servers are dedicated especially to Mongo with no overhead. Total RAM is over 10 GB which more than enough for the kind of queries I am performing (shown below).

My concern is that despite of having indexes to the appropriate fields time to retrieve the result is huge (2 minutes to whopping 30 minutes), which is not acceptable. I am newbie to MongoDB & really in confused state as to why this is happening.

Sample schema is:

```
user:
{
_id: UUID (indexed by default),
name: string,
dob: ISODate,
addr: string,
createdAt: ISODate (indexed),
.
.
.,
transaction:[
{
firstTransaction: ISODate(indexed),
lastTransaction: ISODate(indexed),
amount: float,
product: string (indexed),
.
.
.
},...
],
other sub documents...
}
```

Sub document length varies from 0- 50 or so.

Queries which I performed are:

1) `db.user.find().min({createdAt:ISODate("2014-12-01")}).max({createdAt:ISODate("2014-12-31")}).explain()`

This query worked slow at first, but then was lightning fast(I guess because of warming up).

2) `db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:'mobile'}}}).explain()`

This query took over 30 mins & warming up wasn't of help as every time the performance was same. It returned over half of the collection.

3) `db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:'mobile'}}, firstTransaction:{$in:[ISODate("2015-01-01"),ISODate("2015-01-02")]}}}}).explain()`

This is the main query which I want to be performant. But to my bad luck this query takes more than 30 mins to perform. I tried many versions of it such as this:

`db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:'mobile'}}}).min({transaction:{$elemMatch:{firstTransaction:ISODate("2015-01-01")}}}).max({transaction:{$elemMatch:{firstTransaction:ISODate("2015-01-02")}}}).explain()`

This query gave me error:

> planner returned error: unable to find relevant index for max/min
>   query & with hint():

```
planner returned error: hint provided does not work with min query
```

I used min max function because of the uncertainty of the range queries in MongoDB with $lt, $gt operators, which sometimes ignore either of the bound & end up scanning more documents than needed.

I used indexes such as:

```
db.user.ensureIndex({createdAt: 1})

db.user.ensureIndex({"transaction.firstTransaction":1})

db.user.ensureIndex({"transaction.lastTransaction":1})

db.user.ensureIndex({"transaction.product":1})
```

I tried to use compound indexing for the 3 query, which is:

`db.user.ensureIndex({"transaction.firstTransaction":1, "transaction.product":1})`

But this seems to give me no result. Query gets stuck & never returns the result. I mean it. NEVER. Like deadlocked. I don't know why. So I dropped this index & got the result after waiting for over half an hour (really frustrating).

Please help me out as I am really desperate to find out the solution & out of ideas.

This output might help:

```
Following is the output for:
```

query:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:"mobile", firstTransaction:{$gte:ISODate("2015-01-01"), $lt:ISODate("2015-01-02")}}}}).hint("transaction.firstTransaction_1_transaction.product_1").explain()
```

output:

```
{
        "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
        "shards" : {
                "test0/mrs00.test.com:27017,mrs01.test.com:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1_transaction.firstTransaction_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                "n" : 622,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 350931,
                                "nscanned" : 352000,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 350931,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 352000,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 119503,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 375693,
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "transaction.product" : [
                                                [
                                                        "mobile",
                                                        "mobile"
                                                ]
                                        ],
                                        "transaction.firstTransaction" : [
                                                [
                                                        true,
                                                        ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z")
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                },
                                "server" : "ip-12-0-0-31:27017",
                                "filterSet" : false
                        }
                ],
                "test1/mrs10.test.com:27017,mrs11.test.com:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1_transaction.firstTransaction_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                "n" : 547,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 350984,
                                "nscanned" : 352028,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 350984,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 352028,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 132669,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 891898,
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "transaction.product" : [
                                                [
                                                        "mobile",
                                                        "mobile"
                                                ]
                                        ],
                                        "transaction.firstTransaction" : [
                                                [
                                                        true,
                                                        ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z")
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                },
                                "server" : "ip-12-0-0-34:27017",
                                "filterSet" : false
                        }
                ]
        },
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1_transaction.firstTransaction_1",
        "n" : 1169,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "nYields" : 252172,
        "nscanned" : 704028,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 704028,
        "nscannedObjects" : 701915,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 701915,
        "millisShardTotal" : 1267591,
        "millisShardAvg" : 633795,
        "numQueries" : 2,
        "numShards" : 2,
        "millis" : 891910
}
```

Query:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:'mobile'}}}).explain()
```

Output:

```
{
        "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
        "shards" : {
                "test0/mrs00.test.com:27017,mrs01.test.com:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                "n" : 553072,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 553072,
                                "nscanned" : 553072,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 553072,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 553072,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 164888,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 337909,
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "transaction.product" : [
                                                [
                                                        "mobile",
                                                        "mobile"
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                },
                                "server" : "ip-12-0-0-31:27017",
                                "filterSet" : false
                        }
                ],
                "test1/mrs10.test.com:27017,mrs11.test.com:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                "n" : 554176,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 554176,
                                "nscanned" : 554176,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 554176,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 554176,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 107496,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 327928,
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "transaction.product" : [
                                                [
                                                        "mobile",
                                                        "mobile"
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                },
                                "server" : "ip-12-0-0-34:27017",
                                "filterSet" : false
                        }
                ]
        },
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.product_1",
        "n" : 1107248,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "nYields" : 272384,
        "nscanned" : 1107248,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1107248,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1107248,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1107248,
        "millisShardTotal" : 665837,
        "millisShardAvg" : 332918,
        "numQueries" : 2,
        "numShards" : 2,
        "millis" : 337952
}
```

Please let me know if I have missed any of the details.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what your shard keys are?

Comment: Did you mean to use min and max in your queries? You know they are actually index operators, not query ones right? They are ok if you meant to use them but I thought I would ask, they have slightly different behaviour from $gt and $lt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for performance degradation was the large working set. For some queries (mainly range queries) the set exceeded physical limit & page faults occurred. Due to this performance got degraded.
One solution I did was to apply some filters for the query which will limit the result set & tried to perform equality check instead of the range (iterating over range).
Those tweaks worked for me. Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 4):

1st: Your queries are overly complicated. Using $elemMatch way too often.
2nd: if you can include your shard key in the query it will drastically improve speed.

I'm going to optimize your queries for you:

```
db.user.find({
     createdAt: {
          $gte: ISODate("2014-12-01"), 
          $lte: ISODate("2014-12-31")
     }
}).explain()

db.user.find({
    'transaction.product':'mobile'
}).explain()

db.user.find({
    'transaction.product':'mobile', 
    firstTransaction:{
       $in:[
           ISODate("2015-01-01"),
           ISODate("2015-01-02")
       ]
    }
}).explain()
```

Bottom line is this: include your shard key each time is a time saver.

It might even save time to loop through your shard keys and make the same query multiple times.

Comment: Mongo has index intersectioning as of 2.6, also $in would be better there than $or which is a killer even with the changes in 2.6

Comment: my shard key is _id. Which is user id of type UUID. So, it'll not be possible to include shard key in the query as this is what query should return.I had tried query 2 in your answer but to no avail. Sorry, forgot to include that one. Another issue is with dot '.' operator. If you use that instead of $elemMatch, query will return the result matching either of the condition like OR, not the AND. That's why I used $elemMatch. I don't know much about $min, $max operators. Do they work same as min(), max() functions?

Comment: If you can't include the shard key in reads, you're really not seeing any benefit of sharding for read operations. Hopefully, distributing the writes evenly with a randomly distributed UUID benefits you. Also, please use `$gte` and `$lte` instead of `$min` and `$max` - where did you get the idea about MongoDB ignoring boundaries and scanning too many docs? Please ask a separate question about that because something needs to be clarified there.

Comment: @wdberkeley is right about not seeing any benefit of sharding. I am currently sharding based on region of user and server. I know which server the user hits, and use that shard key to look up the user. When doing that, the mongos knows which shard it needs to search through. This cuts query time from 300-1000 ms to 0-1ms. Also, I changed my answer to include $lte and $gte.

Comment: Thanks wdberkeley & Brian Noah for your help. I do have posted separate question regarding min() & max(), though not related to indexing. Link is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345738/mongodb-min-max-doesnt-support-embedded-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345738/mongodb-min-max-doesnt-support-embedded-document). I will appreciate if you help me out there. I found that issue while querying. Also there is thread on this in jira, [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8610](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8610). Thanks.

Comment: @wdberkely I have posted separate question regarding indexes. Will be glad if you help :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406579/mongodb-index-boundry-constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406579/mongodb-index-boundry-constraints)

Comment: @BrianNoah I have found through the use of `mongostat --discover` that around 2k to 2.5k page faults occur per second on primary of each shard when query is fired. Is it normal? Also warming up doesn't help as there are same number of page faults & very little performance gain (about 1000s of milliseconds).