# MongoDB Index boundry constraints

Tags: mongodb, indexing

During my hands on with MongoDB I came to understand about a problem with MongoDB indexes. Problem is that MongoDB indexes sometimes doesn't enforce the two-end boundaries to query. Here's one of the output I encountered while querying the database:

Query:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:"mobile", firstTransaction:{$gte:ISODate("2015-01-01"), $lt:ISODate("2015-01-02")}}}}).hint("transaction.product_1_transaction.firstTransaction_1").explain()
```

Output:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor transaction.firstTransaction_1_transaction.product_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "n" : 622,
                            "nscannedObjects" : 350931,
                            "nscanned" : 6188185,
                            "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 350931,
                            "nscannedAllPlans" : 6188185,
                            "scanAndOrder" : false,
                            "indexOnly" : false,
                            "nYields" : 235851,
                            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                            "millis" : 407579,
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "transaction.firstTransaction" : [
                                            [
                                                    true,
                                                    ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z")
                                            ]
                                    ],
                                    "transaction.product" : [
                                            [
                                                    "mobile",
                                                    "mobile"
                                            ]
                                    ]
                            },
```

As you can see in above example for firstTransaction field one end of the bound is true instead of date I mentioned. I found the workaround for this is min(), max() functions. I tried those but they not seem to be working with embedded document (transaction is an array of sub document which contains fields like firstTransaction, product etc). I get following error:

Query:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{product:'mobile'}}}).min({transaction:{$elemMatch:{firstTransaction:ISODate("2015-01-01")}}}).max({transaction:{$elemMatch:{firstTransaction:ISODate("2015-01-02")}}})
```

Output:

```
planner returned error: unable to find relevant index for max/min query
```

firstTransaction field is indexed though as well as product & their compound index too. I don't know what is going wrong here.

Sample document:

```
{
_id: UUID (indexed by default),
name: string,
dob: ISODate,
addr: string,
createdAt: ISODate (indexed),
.
.
.,
transaction:[
{
firstTransaction: ISODate(indexed),
lastTransaction: ISODate(indexed),
amount: float,
product: string (indexed),
.
.
.
},...
],
other sub documents...
}
```

Comment: It would be rather helpful to see your query, not just the output of `explain`...

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior. You cannot always intersect the index bounds for `$lte` and `$gte` - sometimes it would give incorrect results. For example, consider the document

```
{ "x" : [{ "a" : [4, 6] }] }
```

This document matches the query

```
db.test.find({ "x" : { "$elemMatch" : { "a" : { "$gte" : 5, "$lte" : 5 } } } });
```

If we define an index on `{ "x.a" : 1 }`, the two index bounds would be `[5, infinity]`, and `[-infinity, 5]`. Intersecting them would give `[5, 5]` and using this index bound would not match the document - incorrectly!

Can you provide a sample document and tell us more about what you're trying to do with the query? With context, there may be another way to write the query that uses tighter index bounds.

Comment: I got your point. Though my field- firstTransaction is not the array throughout collection & I want to restrict on the two index ends in order to confine the search on documents to gain performance. I hope the given sample document helps.

Comment: The example showing that the index bounds behavior involves an array - but the point is that MongoDB doesn't enforce types for fields, so any field always could have an array value. Therefore, even if we are disallowed from intersecting the index bounds only when there are array fields in the embedded document, we are still disallowed from intersecting the bounds in general.

Comment: Also, could you describe the purpose of the query, i.e. what it is trying to achieve for your application, along with the sample doc? You will not be able to achieve the "perfect" index bounds that you might think should apply with the query in its current form.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is to get number of first transactions which occurred for particular product in particular duration. Sample document is as I explained in the question. Do you need me to explain it with data? I want to build report such as who have done their first transaction in the month of Dec '14 for the product "mobile".